# How to display last inserted graph in mp android chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have inserted 40 records. Whenever I open graph, it displays from 1st record to 10 records and need to scroll to right to see other 10 records. How to display the last record initially and makes to scroll from right to left to see other records ie 40 to 30,30 to 20 and so on.

I just given

```
    barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    barChart.setDescription("Activity Tracking");
    ViewPortHandler handlers = barChart.getViewPortHandler();
    handlers.setMaximumScaleX(10);
```

[image]

[image]

I need to display the last 10 inserted record instead of first 10. how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move the view to the right, use the method `public void moveViewTo(float xIndex, float yValue, AxisDependency axis)`

```
            mChart.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mChart.moveViewTo(xIndex, mChart.getBarData().getYMax(),
                            YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT, 1000);
                }
            }, 500);
```

The very first parameter is the index on the X-axis you want to move to. This will scroll the view to the very last element. In case you want it to be animated, you can do

```
            mChart.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mChart.moveViewToAnimated(xIndex, mChart.getBarData().getYMax(),
                            YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT, 1000);
                }
            }, 500);
```

Here the 4th parameter is the time of animation.

So to move to 20th record, put 20 as xIndex, for 30 put 30 etc

Comment: thanks @ankit. I have some query. Wat's that mPlacementChart, listSize and dataSetSize? I used as object of two in the above method...  private BarDataSet dataset;
    private BarData data;  but it's not displaying the method.

Comment: Actually mPlacementChart and mChart are same. It is the bar chart which you want to scroll. I took it directly from my code and forgot to edit it. Also listSize/dataSetSize parameter is the xIndex or the index of value where you want your graph to move to. ex to move the 30th value, pass 29, for 40th pass 39. I was moving it to the very last so I was giving listSize - 1. Edited now to make it more clear

Comment: well thanks for update. For the first method, it's showing but for the second parameter, moveViewToAnimated this method is not showing at all. Is it changed in library? it has moveViewToX,moveViewToY and moveViewTo alone.

Comment: or only the first paramter is fine?

Comment: I am using 2.2.4 and this method is there may be you are using some other version of the library. Method 1 is sufficient. method 2nd was in case you wanted the scroll to be animated. with method 1, it would be moving instantly. Using method 2, the transition would have been visible

Comment: thanks for your update. yes after using 2.2.4 i found the method. Actually i was using 2.2.1. :-)